# Case Insensitive Unique keeping original

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

The easiest way to remove duplicates with case insensitive `unique(tolower(x))` but it makes original values to lowercase. And I want to keep values as it is as there are some short-forms like `SQL`.

```
x <- c("SAS", "Machine Learning", "machine learning", "SQL")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below using `duplicated`

```
x[!duplicated(tolower(x))]
```